# (Dataweave 1.0) Transformed Message includes Namespaces (and should not)

Tags: dataweave

In Dataweave 1.0 the transformed message is not same as the expected message. It is giving namespaces where it should not give.

Output-

`<System>
    <com:CHANNEL_IND xmlns:com="http://bringer.com/SCL/CommonTypes">ABC</CHANNEL_IND>
    <com:UNIQUE_IND xmlns:com="http://bringer.com/SCL/CommonTypes">EFT</UNIQUE_IND>
</System>`

Expected Output-

```
<System xmlns:com="http://bringer.com/SCL/CommonTypes">
<com:CHANNEL_IND>ABC</CHANNEL_IND>
<com:UNIQUE_IND>EFT</UNIQUE_IND>
```

Comment: Can you show the DW transformation that you tried that produces the unexpected output?

Answer (score 4):

It is not a bug, it is prefectly fine both

```
<System xmlns:com="http://bringer.com/SCL/CommonTypes">
     <com:CHANNEL_IND>ABC</com:CHANNEL_IND>
    <com:UNIQUE_IND>EFT</com:UNIQUE_IND>
</Sytem>
```

And

```
<System>
    <com:CHANNEL_IND xmlns:com="http://bringer.com/SCL/CommonTypes">ABC</com:CHANNEL_IND>
    <com:UNIQUE_IND xmlns:com="http://bringer.com/SCL/CommonTypes">EFT</com:UNIQUE_IND>
</System>
```

Are semantically the same as the same nodes are going to reference the same namespace.

Comment: Yes I know.....But is there some way so that it shows exactly the way the expected output is.